# Do we have a new moderator?

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderators, users, community-moderation

I do not recall being introduced to a new moderator: user842563.

[image]

Can the moderation team comment?

Comment: I'm as confused as you are and have contacted SE staff about this

Comment: If it's not a fake image (and I've no reason to think it is) it raises some questions, such as can you enter a name with a diamond character when selecting one ?

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine It's not a fake image, for a brief time this user was displayed as a moderator on both physics.SE and StackOverflow under "moderators", i.e. this is not just an issue with the display name (and I think the diamond unicode symbols are explicitly forbidden in usernames anyway). The problem has since been resolved, but I have no further confirmed information on this and will let staff explain what happened (the status-review tag on this question should eventually summon SE staff).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens every once in a while, though in this case it wasn't for the reasons it usually happens.

Someone made a small error in using our system to give a staff member a diamond and since the user is not staff, they appeared on the mod page. Upon seeing this post we fixed the issue in a short period of time (thanks so much for the report!) and we've since changed the system to prevent this from happening again in this case.

Apologies for the confusion!

Comment: I'm struggling to follow just who did what to whom here, but it won't happen again so all is good.